# How to return binary data from SoapUI REST mock

Tags: soapui

I am trying to create a REST mock service that reads binary data from a file. The mock service needs to send back a HTTP response using just the binary data as content. I do not know the encoding of the binary data. I searched for possible solutions, but I couldn't find any. Can anyone please help me with this issue?

I tried so far to fill the bytes from the file into the response string, but the data appeared to be corrupted when analysed with Postman. In the example below I used a PDF file as input. The code run as script in the MockResponse.

```
def file = new java.io.File("D:/tmp/test.pdf")
byte[] fileBytes = file.getBytes()
String fileString = new String(fileBytes)
mockResponse.setResponseContent(fileString)
```

I am running SoapUI 5.6.0 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I found that it is possible to stream the data from the file to the httpResponse. The following code worked as required:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

def httpResponse = mockRequest.httpResponse
def file = new java.io.File("D:/tmp/test.pdf")

// Set Header values as needed
mockRequest.httpResponse.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
mockRequest.httpResponse.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=test.pdf")

try {

  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
  OutputStream os = httpResponse.getOutputStream()

  IOUtils.copy(fis,os)

} catch (Exception e){
  log.info " error"
}
finally {
  fis.close()
  os.close()
}
```